# Deluge script Zoho books Zoho Flow

Tags: zoho-deluge

How to creat automation in zoho books with zoho flow from zoho books sale orders print in my printer the name and the date of the order.When the order save as draft what is The deluge script for this ?
I would like anyone with this script that help:)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.